# Inverting a bubble interface to recover the level set function

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, phase-transition, bubbles

I have access to some high quality CFD data that includes 2D and 3D level set functions for simulations of bubbles. Masking the level set function using a heaviside is easy and it is a fast way to get the interface of the bubble.

For some interesting applications to my research I want to see if I can go from the interface back to the level set function. The level set function is typically a signed distance function to the interface. So, since I have access to where the interface locations are I am computing the distance function as such.

$$\phi = \inf\{d(x,y)\}, \quad d(x,y) = \sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2}$$

Here $(x_i, y_i)$ is the interface point and $\phi$ is the smallest distance from any point (x,y) to that interface location. Here is what that looks like compared to the ground truth level set function.

[image]

As you can see the images are qualitatively similar but the sign of the inside of the bubbles are wrong and this will make futher computations incorrect but also when there are more bubbles it washes away a lot of information inbetween bubbles. Does anybody have an idea on how to appropriately sign the distance function so that my predicted level set matches more closely the ground truth?

Also, the white points are the interface points. Thanks!

Comment: it looks like you're not computing a signed distance, but just distance as a non-negative quantity. You're not using the information 0/1 given by the Heaviside's function: you could try to set $d=-\sqrt{\dots}$ when the point falls inside a bubble, and keep the positive sign outside. Let me know

Comment: Required reading: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/end-of-the-rainbow-new-map-scale-is-more-readable-by-people-who-are-color-blind/, https://www.kennethmoreland.com/color-advice/BadColorMaps.pdf (PDF warning), https://agilescientific.com/blog/2017/12/14/no-more-rainbows, etc.

Comment: @basics Thanks for pointing this out. I do this in a later code, the issue arrises when there is more than one bubble. I am not sure how to find the center of the bubbles without manually placing the center on each image. I know there are methods for learning dynamic level set functions like the fast marching method, but I just want to be able to find the level set function for a single arbitrary image of the bubble.